# Getting coordinates of word in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I'm trying to remove text from a particular section of a PDF. If I know the X,Y co-ordinates of the area, I'm able to remove the text.
So for that i have to use word/text to find co-ordinates.I have searched for solution but could not find.

Please suggest any snippet/code

Comment: *As you use [tag:itext] and not [tag:itext7], I assume you mean iText 5.5.x.* ... by googl'ing for "itext extract text position" on stackoverflow.com, you'll get multiple hits. And even though many of them are for iTextSharp and C#, it should be easy to port those solutions to iText and Java. Have you tried that?

Comment: by using pdfTextStripper i have solved the problem by overiding the writeString method.